# error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3

Tags: c++, qt

I have this error appearing when trying to build a C++ project which uses QT.

[image: My error]

I've checked the below link but the user didn't say the solution.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/5b0be7be-1b6e-44c2-91ca-b5a9a55a2c41/

The warnings appearing are:

Warning 1

> The element 'PropertyGroup' in
>   namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has
>   invalid child element 'IntDirTrailingSlashWarning' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'. List of
>   possible elements expected: 'Property, AllowUnsafeBlocks,
>   AppConfigForCompiler, ApplicationIcon, ApplicationRevision,
>   ApplicationVersion, AppDesignerFolder, AspNetConfiguration,
>   AssemblyKeyContainerName, AssemblyKeyProviderName, AssemblyName,
>   AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile, AssemblyOriginatorKeyFileType,
>   AssemblyOriginatorKeyMode, AssemblyType, AutorunEnabled, BaseAddress,
>   BootstrapperComponentsLocation, BootstrapperComponentsUrl,
>   BootstrapperEnabled, CharacterSet, CheckForOverflowUnderflow,
>   CLRSupport, CodePage, Configuration, ConfigurationName,
>   ConfigurationOverrideFile, CreateDesktopShortcut,
>   CreateWebPageOnPublish, CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents,
>   DebugSecurityZoneURL, DebugSymbols, DebugType, DefaultClientScript,
>   DefaultHTMLPageLayout, DefaultTargetSchema, DefineConstants,
>   DefineDebug, DefineTrace, DelaySign, DisableLangXtns,
>   DisallowUrlActivation, CodeAnalysisAdditionalOptions,
>   CodeAnalysisApplyLogFileXsl, CodeAnalysisConsoleXsl,
>   CodeAnalysisCulture, CodeAnalysisFailOnMissingRules,
>   CodeAnalysisForceOutput, CodeAnalysisGenerateS....    C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  21

and

Warning 59

> The 'ToolArchitecture' attribute is not
>   declared. C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  713

This is the file having the error:
[error file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5gc9399p3m279o/Microsoft.CppCommon.targets)
This is the log file:
[log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gp4vrmd2aiet9d7/QtDataAcquisition.log)

Comment: Any further error pointing to codes / resources ?

Comment: show the build log please.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773122/qt-visual-studio-work-with-projects-on-multiple-computers

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I've uploaded the log file if you could please assist me

Comment: any luck? I'm having the same issue and I couldn't find any solution for it ...

Comment: "closed as too localized"?? how was this determined?  Jeez, sometimes SO gets too "close" happy on questions.

Answer (score 4):

In your build log, some files are missing, hence the build action is failed. Review these errors:

```
"\bin\rcc.exe" -name "qtdataacquisition" -no-compress "D:\hussein\KinectQtDataAcquisition\KinectQtDataAcquisition\qtdataacquisition.qrc" -o .\GeneratedFiles\qrc_qtdataacquisition.cpp
         The system cannot find the path specified.
         Moc'ing qtdataacquisition.h...
         Uic'ing qtdataacquisition.ui...
         The system cannot find the path specified.
         Moc'ing DataCollector.h...
         The system cannot find the path specified.
         The system cannot find the path specified.
         Rcc'ing qtdataacquisition.qrc...
     1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3.
```

Comment: this path was found "D:\hussein\KinectQtDataAcquisition\KinectQtDataAcquisition\qtdataacquisition.qrc", so what can I check for next?

Comment: check permission as well, is it writable ?

Comment: I've made it full control and rebuild but still same error

Comment: How about path : `D:\hussein\KinectQtDataAcquisition\KinectQtDataAcquisition\GeneratedFiles\` ? seems it can't be written in this path. Make sure you "Clean & Re-build"

Comment: this path have a full control"r/w anything"

Comment: by the user group `EVERYONE` ?

Comment: yes, for the usergroup "Everyone", I've put a pic showing the error, if you could check it and try to help me.

Comment: That's weird. noticed you have quite a lot of warnings, does any of the warning give you clues ?

Comment: nope, i don't think they are related to the error. I've put the two types of warnings in my question. The other thing, you'll find red dots in couple of the solution files on the right, if i opened any of these files the errors will be more, I don't know why

Comment: Why my question was closed?