# can not build qt 5.2 project in visual studio 2012 which uses openscenegraph after osg compile cmake

Tags: visual-studio-2012, openscenegraph, qt5.2

I am writing a QT 5.2 project in Visual Studio 2012. The project uses OpenSceneGraph 3.2(osg). Firstly I compiled osg with cmake. But It was difficult. Then I want to build QT project but following errors is given.

```
1>  Moc'ing cadview.h...
1>  The device is not ready.
1>  Rcc'ing Resources\cadstork.qrc...
1>  The device is not ready.
```

ALso I added QT and OSG path to project properties and environment variables.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

See the answers, eg, here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6773325/1339735

Or many other QT-building answers.  From those answers, it seems like Moc and Rcc do not share your project's include paths, you'll have to add them manually to the command line arguments of the build step.